# Firefox addon to call javascript functions loaded from a server, is it feasible?

Tags: javascript, firefox, autofill

I am evaluating the feasibility of automating the entries of bets submitted to a server.   As there are lots of bets for entry, it would be too slow to key in before the race starts and press the "submit" button (labelled "Add to Slip"), therefore automatic entry is preferable.

The manual method:

The web page coming from the server is "http://bet.hkjc.com/default.aspx?url=/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx&lang=en&langRedirect=true#r_shortcut_e".   Entries of bets involve clicking the Banker and Sel. columns, and the javascript would store them in some variables, a click on the "add to Slip" button would cause the bet entry to store into some other variables in another iframe on the right of the screen.   Having entered sets of bets, a click on the "Send Bet" button would send the bets to the server.

The intended automation:

The bets to enter would be available from a java program on the PC, and can be made available to the firefox addon via a file.  The addon reads the file and recursively put the entries inside the variables and call the "Add to Slip" function. The click on the "send bet" button can be done manually.

The addon is like a facility automatically fill in fields for a web page.

As I am entirely new to addon and javascript development, is this the correct approach ? Or is there any other way to implement this ?

Please enlighten me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Java program on your PC, why do you need Firefox at all?  A Java program is perfectly capable of making any call to the server that Firefox can make.  (See java.net).

Comment: The Jockey Club server only accepts bets via their own web page; and there is sign on to identify the bettor before accepting any bets.

Comment: Mwahahahaha.  The Jockey Club *thinks* its server only accepts bets via their own web page.  See [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup/) for ways to subvert the dominant paradigm.

Comment: Thanks, Mwahahahaha.  I browsed through the description of Beautiful Soup.   It appeared to me that it was a parser and data extractor for html and xml file; primarily used to extract data from a web page.  Correct me if I were wrong.  Sorry, I could not think of ways to use it to "cheat" the server that it is accepting bets via their own web page.   Could you elaborate ?

Comment: When the Jockey Club "accepts" a bet, that means that something downloaded an HTML page, interpreted it, added some data, and made a POST back to the server (typically at least twice: first for the log-in and then for the actual bet).  They are expecting the something to be a browser operated by a person, but BeautifulSoup is a good way of automating the process.

Comment: Using the python and Beautiful Soup approach, I have to learn python and the Soup API.  That would make the implementation time too longer for me.    However, it seems that my original approach is impossible as the addon codes are not allowed to call java script functions coming from Web, which as explained is due to security exposure.   Is my understanding correct ?   If so, I have to abandon this approach.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but a security constraint does sound plausible.  Have you considered contracting the job out?

Comment: That depends on the cost.

Comment: You can message me on Reddit /u/malvoliosf

Comment: What is the meaning of "Reddit /u/malvoliosf" ?   Sorry, I don't know how to message you.

Comment: Sorry, Reddit is big social networking site: http:/www.reddit.com  .  You can go to my page, http:/www.reddit.com/u/malvoliosf , and send me a message.